# Group activities in activity feed by users and products

Tags: mysql, php, aggregate

On my website I'm building an activity feed where I got the basics done and are now making some improvements here and there.

One of them is the grouping. I've built it so that if multiple users buys the same 2 or more products the activity feed shows it as one activity: "user1 & user2 bought product 1, 2 & 3".

The problem is that if user1 buys product 1 & 2 and user2 buys product 1, 2 & 3 it appears as two different activities: "user1 bought product 1 & 2" AND "user2 bought product 1, 2 & 3".

I would like it to show as "user1 & user2 bought product 1 & 2" and then another saying "user2 bought product 3"

I've made a simplified [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee175/10) of what I've got so far. Try changing it by deleting NULL, 'Bought', 1, 3

Is this something that is possible to do in MySQL or should I do it in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group users by activity and product in the first step, and *then* group products by the groups of users.
I use `ORDER BY` with `GROUP_CONCAT()`, so that the aggregated usernames are concatenated in the same order.

```
SELECT x.usernames
      ,x.activity
      ,GROUP_CONCAT(p.product_name ORDER BY p.product_name) AS product_names
FROM   products p
JOIN  (
   SELECT a.activity
         ,a.productId
         ,GROUP_CONCAT(u.name ORDER BY u.name) AS usernames
   FROM   activities a
   LEFT   JOIN users u ON u.id = a.userId
   GROUP  BY 1, 2
   ) x ON x.productId = p.id
GROUP  BY 1, 2
ORDER  BY 1, 2;
```

[-> sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0657/6)

Returns:

```
USERNAMES  | ACTIVITY   | PRODUCT_NAMES
-----------+------------+------------------------------
John       | Bought     | The Dark Knight Rises
John,Peter | Bought     | Batman Begins,The Dark Knight
```

Comment: @Oskar, do you run additional mysql queries through PHP, when you parse the concatenated result, e.g. usernames from Erwin's sqlfiddle?.